# flow type React ref callback and createRef

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

```jsx
class Component extends React.Component<ComponentProps> {
  // ...magic
  elementRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.elementRef);
  }
}
```

This is a component I have. Its basically passing the ref callback to children. 
and then its used like this

```jsx
<Component>
  {elementRef => (
    <div ref={elementRef} />
  )}
</Component>
```

The intention of my `Component` is that the children can attach the `elementRef` to any element.

But I having a lot of trouble type my component correctly.

What I am doing right now:

```jsx
type ComponentProps = {
  +children: (
    ref: { current: HTMLDivElement | null } | ((ref: ?HTMLDivElement) => void)
  ) => React.Node,
};
```

But obviously this only works for `div`. If I were to use the elementRef on a span. Flow would complain.

So how should I type my `Component` correctly so that it works for any HTML element?

Comment: Can't you just use `HTMLElement` instead?

Comment: It will complain as `HTMLElement` is not compatible with `HTMLDivElement` or any other html element types

Comment: Will generics help here? Something like [this](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBdkwBDAZzACUBTUgY2KnzizAHJ87H2BuVQgE8cNMAAkAKgFkAMgFEYNLDQB2xALxgA3gF9+A4aIDCrPCtWEACixzkAPBLAAucdPmLlagHxhNW1GBgANT0ABYYMAAmXCouABQBgWBcUC5aYPQArvgxhC6OAD5gKpkwMGA6YEVxcSkuAPwSAJS+PgBucBiRTYkt6j60DIQAdABycJE0ADSoeuj0MBSUJrhw5mpgNAAehKqRlIOMwytmFnYnaxbWcLZ2IF4+-oHAwGDD71ikAOYY9Ik0HgstCgvmo3BG9C4pF2wLiTX0gRik3wcO0iURNEI2RUYEI4XIwxwNgJYQi0VUcTxGAJAKUQJoUHhiR0syAA)

Comment: Take a look at React.ComponentType<> with the existential type ‘*’ for props. https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype

Answer (score 3):

I think [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/b76ad725177284681d483247e89739c292ed982b/lib/react.js#L219-L220) might solve your problem. It's not yet in the docs.

```
{current: null | React$ElementRef<ElementType>}
```